# Linear regression with shot noise

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, heteroscedasticity, errors-in-variables

I'm looking for the right statistical terminology to describe the following problem.

I want to characterize an electronics device that has a linear response

$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \epsilon$

where $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2_{ro})$ is a term due to the read-out noise of the device. In order to determine $\beta_0, \beta_1, \sigma^2_{ro}$ I would measure a series of responses $\{X_i,Y_i\}$ and apply the standard linear regression toolbox. But I don't know what the $X_i$ are exactly, because I use a source that is affected by shot noise. That is I know that if I set the dial on the source to a certain value $J_i$ then $X_i \sim N(\mu, \mu)$ (a Gaussian with average $\mu$ and variance $\mu$).

This looks like an errors-in-variables model of linear regression (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models), where not for the fact that in order to characterize my device over its entire input range, during the measurements I have to change the value of $J_i$, and now the variance of the $X_i$ is not fixed, but it depends on $X_i$ (through J_i), although because of the shot noise if $X_i=X_j$ this does not mean that the variance of $X_i$ is the same as the variance of $X_j$.

What is this model called, and are there articles where I can find out such a problem is approached? Or am I formulating in the wrong manner?

Comment: Var(Xi)=μ=E(Xi)>0. If this were fixed then this would be an error in variables model with variance ratio σ$^2$ $_ro$/μ. It isn't because μ changes with the Xi. I have seen models with non constant variance in Y and models with errors in variables but not this type of model which has errors in variables with non-constant variance.  When the variance in Y is not constant sometimes it is possible to model the variance as a function of the value of the covariate x.  Maybe something like that could be done for the error in X.

Answer (score 3):

The probability model for such shot noise is

$$X \sim \text{Poisson}(\mu),\quad Y|X \sim \text{Normal}(\beta_0+\beta_1 X, \sigma^2).$$

A good estimate of $\mu$ is the mean of $X$ and a good estimate of $(\beta_0, \beta_1)$ is afforded by ordinary least squares, because the values of $Y$ are assumed independent, identically distributed, and normal.

The estimate of $\sigma^2$ given by OLS is inappropriate here, though, due to the randomness of $X$. The maximum likelihood estimate is

$$s^2 = \frac{S_{xy}^2 - 2 S_x S_y S_{xy} + S_{xx}\left(S_y^2 - S_{yy}\right) + S_x^2 S_{yy}}{S_x^2 - S_{xx}}.$$

In this notation, $S_x$ is the mean $X$ value, $S_{xy}$ is the mean of the products of the $X$ and $Y$ values, etc.

**We can expect the standard errors of estimation in the two approaches** (OLS, which is not quite right, and MLE as described here) **to differ**. There are various ways to obtain ML standard errors: consult a reference.  Because the log likelihood is relatively simple (especially when the Poisson$(\mu)$ distribution is approximated by a Normal$(\mu,\mu)$ distribution for large $\mu$), these standard errors can be computed in closed form if one desires.

---

**As a worked example,** I generated $12$ $X$ values from a Poisson$(100)$ distribution:

```
94,99,106,87,91,101,90,102,93,110,97,123
```

Then, setting $\beta_0=3$, $\beta_1=1/2$, and $\sigma=1$, I generated $12$ corresponding $Y$ values:

```
47.4662,53.5622,54.6656,45.3592,49.0347,53.8803,48.3437,54.2255,48.4506,58.6761,50.7423,63.9922
```

The mean $X$ value equals $99.4167$, the estimate of $\mu$. The OLS results (which are identical to the MLE of the coefficients) estimate $\beta_0$ as $1.24$ and $\beta_1$ as $0.514271$.  It is no surprise the estimate of the intercept, $\beta_0$, departs from its true value of $3$, because these $X$ values stay far from the origin.  The estimate of the slope, $\beta_1$, is close to the true value of $0.5$.

The OLS estimate of $\sigma^2$, however, is $0.715$,  less than the true value of $1$. The MLE of $\sigma^2$ works out to $0.999351$.  (It is an accident that both estimates are low and that the MLE is greater than the OLS estimate.)

[image: Figure]

*The line is both the OLS fit and the maximum likelihood estimate for the joint Poisson-Normal probability model.*